# Apart from Kafka-connect FileConfigProvider, Do we have anything like LdapConfigProvider?

Tags: jdbc, apache-kafka, ldap, apache-kafka-connect

Need to create kafka-connect JdbcSinkConnector for Oracle DB using Datasource details which are externalized in LDAP.

Following are the connector details kafka-connect-jdbc/sink-quickstart-oracle.properties where connection details like **connection.url**, **connection.username**, **connection.password** etc. should come from LDAP.

```
    name=test-sink
    connector.class=io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSinkConnector
    tasks.max=1
    topics=orders
    connection.url= ???? #should be sourced from LDAP
    connection.username= ???? #should be sourced from LDAP
    connection.password= ???? #should be sourced from LDAP
    auto.create=true
```

Comment: Provide your sample code, how you are doing and what error you are getting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Out of the box, Kafka does not provide such a feature or configuration.

As part of [KIP-297](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-297%3A+Externalizing+Secrets+for+Connect+Configurations), you would have to write/find your own implementation of a `ConfigProvider` from which you could do an LDAP lookup, and add that built JAR to your Connect workers' classpaths.

Comment: Besides, I'd say this is up to your database driver to implement. The username and password configs are optional. The url is not. If you can encode ldap information into the url, then the driver is responsible for handling it